# Which Luftwaffe units participated in the raid on Manchester on 11 March 1941?

Tags: world-war-two, military, aircraft

Which Luftwaffe units participated in the raid on Manchester on 11 March 1941?

Answer (score 5):

There doesn't seem to be a specific answer to this question, although this is the general [Order of Battle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luftwaffe_Order_of_Battle_August_1940) for the Luftwaffe around that period.

Responsible for the Northwest (Manchesters section) bombings were units of the [Luftflotte 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luftflotte_3) (Air fleet 3), supported by elements of Luftflotte 1 and 4, respectably.

When reading background information about the Old Trafford bombing (which, I assume you imply). I narrowed down the possibilities to the bombing corps of Luftflotte 3, which would be [X.Fliegerkorps (X. Air Corps) Angers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luftflotte_3#X.Fliegerkorps_.28X.Air_Corps.29_Angers).

I'm afraid it's impossible to retrace which exact elements were responsible for the raid.